# php5-fpm shuts down automatically for no apparent reason

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, php, digital-ocean

I have an ubuntu 14 server running nginx. I use it for a WordPress website

Out of the blue for no reason the php5-fpm shuts down automatically (I am not sure it even is called shutdown, I get the nginx error page).

This is the message I get now on my site::

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please
>   try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

I restarted the php5-fpm from the command line and my site goes up for 30-40 seconds and then it goes down again.

What can be the reason? How can the php5-fpm decided on itself to do this? If it helps I'll add that this is a digital ocean server

Thanks upfront!

Comment: Is there any useful error output in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` ? That's usally the first place to look when debugging an issue like this.

Comment: Would be helpful if you had some error logs and configurations to post.

Comment: Have you configure your php processor and nginx to use our php processor.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909355/wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-nginx/36922101#36922101)! to solve.

Its because your resource was fully utilized by xmlrpc.php. Possibly Brute force attack.

Block access to xmlrpc.php in nginx config.